# Class Library with Models not getting Xml Comments using Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a **.net core 2.1 class library for my models** that I use in multiple **asp.net core web api** projects. I am using **Swagger(version 3.0.0)** for my API documentation. The **Xml Comments** are **NOT** displayed for the models in the class library. Yes, I have **IncludeXmlComments** in my Startup.cs. How do I get the Xml Comments working in my models class library?

NOTE: My models in my Projects directory are documented correctly by Swagger.

Here is where I include the Xml comments:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { 
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Web API", Version = "v1" }); 
    c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\ABC.Application.WebApi.xml"); 
});
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code, specifically the part where you use the `IncludeXmlComments`

Comment: Here is where I include the Xml comments: services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Web API", Version = "v1" });
                
                c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\ABC.Application.WebApi.xml");
            });

Comment: Looks like you have only one `IncludeXmlComments` but you should have at least two one for your WebApi and the other for the class library that has your models.

Answer (score 3):

Any referenced assemblies will have to be added individually. ABC.Application.WebApi.xml will not contain xml comments from your shared models class.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { 
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Web API", Version = "v1" }); 
    c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\ABC.Application.WebApi.xml"); 
    c.IncludeXmlComments($@"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\YourSharedClass.Models.xml"); 
});
```

You may need to copy the model xml to your project. Reference: [Add NuGet package XML documentation to Swagger](https://snede.net/add-nuget-package-xml-documentation-to-swagger/)